# Copy file with certain name into a new folder

Tags: powershell, create-directory

I have a powershell script that will search through the sub folders of a directory and copy any files that contain a specific string in the name and then move those into a different folder that it creates. The problem I am having is that the script is not creating and new folder but just a new file without an extension. Here is my script.

```
 Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\users\user1\Documents\q3\' -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "*test2*" -and $_.FullName -notmatch 'newfolder' } | Copy-Item -Destination 'C:\Users\user1\Documents\Q3\test'
```

Comment: The searching works how I want it to. The problem is that powershell is not creating the 'test' folder. If that folder already exists then there is no problem. I just want powershell to create that folder instead of me having to do it each time.

Comment: you're going to want to add ```if{-not (test-path $folder_path)}(mkdir $folder_path)``` or similar to the script beginning. test for the path of the folder, make it if it isn't there already, then continue.

Answer (score 0):

There is no parameter with a behavior like: "createifnotexist" for directories in powershell's **copy-item()** function. (I'm using powershell 5.1 and could not find one)

This is a way to achieve your goal with a one liner

```bsh
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Name "test" -Path 'C:\Users\user1\Documents\Q3' -Force; Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\users\user1\Documents\q3\' -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "*test2*" -and $_.FullName -notmatch 'newfolder' } | % { Copy-Item -Path "C:\Users\user1\Documents\Q3\test\"}
```

The **New-Item** will override the latest created folder with the **-Force**